# php file uploading doesn't work

Tags: php, file

I am testing a php code of file uploading. Here is the form:

```
<form action="C:/xampp/htdocs/php/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Browse File</p>
    <p><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

and here is the upload.php file:

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']){
$upload_folder = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/php/uploads/';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_folder.$_FILES['file']['name']);
echo 'File uploaded successfully';
}
?>
```

But this doesn't upload any file. What is the problem here?

Comment: First of all, always use relative path instead of absolute path

Comment: It's more useful to show you some troubleshooting techniques than to attempt to troubleshoot this for you:  Does `upload.php` even run? How do you know? What does it output if you add `var_dump($_POST);` to the top of the file? What does it output if you add `var_dump($_FILES);`? Do you have errors turned on? If not, turn them on.

Comment: Do you get an error or anything? First thing that stands out is that your `action` is pointing to a "C:\..." directory. If you do that, your php file isn't going to be served by apache (unless you've got some sort of crazy setup). You should have something like `<form action="./php/upload.php" [...]>` or something.

Comment: All these comments that state you have to use relative paths are technically incorrect: you can also use the *full url* to your file, something like `http://localhost/upload.php`, for example, works great.

Comment: May be your form action path are wrong..
In form tag pass only upload.php in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the C: path and replace with a relative link to the location of your upload file.

From your original post, if the location of your files on the local hardware is:

```
  htdocs/php/uploads/
```

Then htdocs is probably the root, so / will point to the htdocs location, to get to your upload.php, you would specify:

```
  /php/uploads/upload.php
```

However if htdocs isn't your root, then just adjust accordingly.

Comment: Yes, just not an absolute location on the locale hardware.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$files = @$_FILES["files"];
if ($files["name"] != '') {
    $fullpath = $_REQUEST["path"] . $files["name"];
    if (move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'], $fullpath)) {
        echo "<h1><a href='$fullpath'>OK!</a></h1>";
    }
}echo '
    <html>
            <head>
                <title>File Upload</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form method=POST enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
                    <input type=text name=path>
                    <input type="file" name="files">
                    <input type=submit value="Up">
                </form>
            </body>
    </html>
        ';
?>
```

Comment: Still not right, you need a return after the echo in the condition where you test move_uploaded_file, also you need html and body wrappers.

Comment: If you are getting away with it then you should check your server error logs, it isn't right.

Comment: I do not understand the downvote since this is absolutely working fine. What would you change exactly (in code)? Thanks.

Comment: Then you are probably using a Microsoft system that allows you to do all kinds of non standard stuff, like using tags without closers.

Comment: Do you run a non-microsoft system? If so, please try asap.

Comment: Of course, it's nice if you could improve the script. Why not?

Comment: But I still really hope that you try this script yourself.

Comment: @SPlatten a `return` as in exiting a function and (optionally) returning a value? Or a return as in a carriage return? The code here looks perfectly valid for *nix, assuming that user input from the form is fine.

Comment: A die will do the job of the echo and return.

Comment: Thank you. I actually began wondering if the script was bugging, but I tried on a non-microsoft server as well and it works like a charm + it is compact.

Comment: So, @SPlatten your change works fine too... But, to be honest, it is just a bit more code that is not necessary at all in my opinion.

Comment: Check the w3c standards, you  are getting away with your code because of the browser and platform, but if you use other browsers and other systems that are fully complaint, it will error.

Comment: Tried via browserling, an interactive cross-browser testing website of a friend of mine, and it works fine too. Different platforms too. So, sorry, but I  believe you are not right in this case.

Comment: Now you are just jumping to standards trying to prove that this is wrong. But if it isn't standard, less code, but works in all cases then why should I use standards?  Alright, this is stupid.

Comment: omg,  stupid is as stupid does, the standards are they're so that the code you write will for correctly on all platforms, not just the one you may be using.

Comment: Proves that you don't even read my previous comments since I proved that it works on all platforms and browsers and people. You are based on assumptions man, I aint having it.

Comment: It isn't an assumption at all, you haven't supplied headers identifying the content type, document size etc, I suspect you don't have warnings enabled  or you don't know how to check the output properly, Mozilla with Firebug or its built in debugger will give you warnings.

Comment: @SPlatten I think I misunderstood the point you were making. Are you just pointing out that this answer will be outputting HTML before the opening <html> tag? I'm trying to understand what exactly you find wrong with this answer, and which portion of the standards you're referring to. Your comments went from "check the server logs" (which shouldn't be recording anything to do with a client browser's rendering), to "check the w3c standards". Encapsulating the form html in an "else" block would probably be better than including a hard `return` or `die` in an answer.

Comment: Thanks Robbie, really just; everything what you say. Thanks.